# How to get the url of image from a json file

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I've written this statement to get the url of image which is stored in a json file BUT the returned data is null and my emulator has crashed !!

```
String url=ent.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("media$thumbnail").getJSONObject(0).getString("url").toString();
```

[image: the object that contains the image url]

is there any logical error in the syntax of this statement ?

Comment: do u mean the image url ?

Comment: nope, the way you retrieve the Strinh url

Comment: yes I've tried to retrieve name :String authorName=ent.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("author").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("name").getString("$t"); ::: and I've succeeded

Comment: this is what I want to know ???? :(  :(

Comment: do the following thing: Instead of concat all the object, cut the `ent.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("media$thumbnail").getJSONObject(0).getString("url").toString();` in pieces, in order to understand what is null

Comment: crash => post stacktrace.

Comment: @blackbelt: thanks I've known where is the problem , this object is contained in another object which is "media$group" ^___^!

Answer (score 2):

Use Jsoup to solve this problem in easiest

http://www.jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document/

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> searchList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
  String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
  Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
  NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PRODUCT);
  for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
  Cursor cousor_image = null;
  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
  Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
      map.put(KEY_PRODUCT_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRODUCT_ID));
      searchList.add(map);
      Element elm = (Element) n3.item(0);
```

This is code define im XMLparser classes

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.i("XML Parser", "xml=" + xml);
```

Below code will help to collect the bitmap to image

```
   public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }

    else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}
```

And finally memorycache class

```
     import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
     import java.util.Collections;
     import java.util.HashMap;
     import java.util.Map;
     import android.graphics.Bitmap;

     public class MemoryCache {
private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache = Collections
        .synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>());

public Bitmap get(String id) {
    if (!cache.containsKey(id))
        return null;
    SoftReference<Bitmap> ref = cache.get(id);
    return ref.get();
}

public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
    cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
}

public void clear() {
    cache.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: op wants to parse the json file to get the url.